# determining an integral using only derivative properties

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Please note that this question is different from a similiar one as although the basis is the same, the integral that is being calculated is different.

let $\alpha′(x)=β(x),β′(x)=α(x) $ and assume that $\alpha^2 - \beta^2 = 1 $. how would I go about calculating the following anti derivative : $\int\alpha^2(x)/\beta^4(x) dx $.

I have tried several methods which did not work. These included putting the integral in terms of one of the variables using the first given condition and then trying to apply an U-substitution. However, since both $\alpha(x)$ and $\beta(x)$ are raised to even numbered powers, I end up with either an $\alpha'(x)$ or $\beta'(x)$ which makes it such that I cannot U-substitute since I cannot rewrite the entire integral in terms of U. 
 I would appreciate any help. 
 Thank you.

Comment: You should make an account and use it for all your questions (and accept the answers)... To solve this think about the integration of $\ln(x)$.

Comment: @N74 I have tried that approach however I have found that it leads to a dead end due to the power of $\alpha(x)$ and $\beta(x)$ as eventually I would be required to do integration by parts for 3 terms with chain rule within one term.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici the question I have asked here is actually very different to the other question. Although the conditions are the same, the integral which must be calculated is not.

Comment: Well, you're right, $\ln x$ suggestion don't bring anywhere... but you can multiply numerator and denominator for the same quantity, try $\beta'$ for the numerator and $\alpha$ for the denominator.

Comment: You can also try $u=\alpha / \beta$. This simplyfies very much the problem.